# Android Textview not aligning to top of page

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having trouble aligning my UI components to top of the constraint layout even though I have constraint them to the start of the page. There is a tiny gap between the ToolBar and where the UI components start. app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" -> this line of code always works but I believe the problem could be that I am using a tabbed activity that it might not be compatible.[Problem in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYMgK.jpg)
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
This is my XML class ->

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breakfastTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Breakfast"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/breakfastRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/breakfastTV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lunchTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Lunch"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/breakfastRecyclerView" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lunchRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lunchTV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dinnerTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Dinner"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lunchRecyclerView" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dinnerRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dinnerTV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/otherTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="Other"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dinnerRecyclerView" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/otherRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otherTV" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

CLASS WITH Toolbar ->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Management"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/topNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/topNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/mgmt_bottom_nav_bar" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: add app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" to scrollview.. if its not working then problem is in your toolbar probably. let me know further

Comment: @RezaulKarim adding that line did not solve the issue I have edited my question above to add the class that has the toolbar above please let me know if I have made a mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this problem is occurring due to the toolbar because I have noticed the same problem in one more activity now